# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{\omega \in A_n} f(\omega) = \inf_{\omega \in A} f(\omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P}$ and $\{A_n, n \geq 1\}$ $\subset \mathscr{F}, A \in \mathscr{F}$. Suppose the sequence of events $A_n \uparrow A$ is increasing and $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any function. Prove that

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{\omega \in A_n} f(\omega) = \inf_{\omega \in A} f(\omega) $

Thus far I have:

Since $A_n \subset A$ we have that $\inf_{\omega \in A} f(\omega) \leq \inf_{\omega \in A_n} f(\omega)$ and therefore also that  $\inf_{\omega \in A} f(\omega) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{\omega \in A_n} f(\omega)$.

Comment: If it's "that trivial", why don't you do it ;-)

Comment: To begin with, $f$ is just "noise" in this statement. What you want to prove is that $\lim_n \inf T_n = \inf T$ where $T_n$ is a set of real numbers increasing to $T.$ (Your $T_n = f(A_n).$) Indeed $\inf T \leq \inf T_n$ is obvious (and so, the limit will keep the inequality), but why the other direction? (Notice that your argument does is define $g_n = \inf T_n$ and then show $g_n \to g$ for some $g$ and this $g$ satisfies $g \geq \inf T.$)

Comment: Don’t you mean $g \leq \inf T$